# SQL - Fastest algorithm to get result from joining two tables

Tags: sql, algorithm, join, pythagorean

SQL to get result from two tables joined on multiple columns the most efficient way:

T1:

```
+---+-----+---+----+
| A | B   | C | D  |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 1 | 111 | W | 11 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 2 | 222 | X | 22 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 3 | 333 | Y | 33 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 4 | 444 | Z | 44 |
+---+-----+---+----+
```

T2:

```
+---+-----+---+----+
| A | B   | C | D  |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 1 | 112 | W | 11 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 2 | 222 | X | 99 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 3 | 333 | Y | 88 |
+---+-----+---+----+
| 4 | 444 | W | 44 |
+---+-----+---+----+
```

I want to match three columns: `T1.A = T2.A`, `T1.B = T2.B`, `T1.C = T2.C`, and get the highest Pythagorean theorem result of `T1.D` and `T2.D`

So for T1 and T2, only these rows match:

```
 T1                    T2                
+---+-----+---+----+  +---+-----+---+----+
| A | B   | C | D  |  | A | B   | C | D  |
+---+-----+---+----+  +---+-----+---+----+
| 2 | 222 | X | 22 |  | 2 | 222 | X | 99 |
+---+-----+---+----+  +---+-----+---+----+
| 3 | 333 | Y | 33 |  | 3 | 333 | Y | 88 |
+---+-----+---+----+  +---+-----+---+----+
```

But 
[image] and [image]

So the only row that should be returned as result is:

```
+---+-----+---+------+------+--------+
| A | B   | C | T1.D | T2.D | E      |
+---+-----+---+------+------+--------+
| 2 | 222 | X | 22   | 99   | 101.41 |
+---+-----+---+------+------+--------+
```

I have something like this:

```
select top 1 t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.D, sqrt(square(case t1.D when null then 0 else t1.D end) + square(case t2.D when null then 0 else t2.D end)) as E
from t1
left join t2 on t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and t1.C=t2.C
order by E desc
```

However, I have tons and tons of data, so it's reeeaally slow (hours). Is there a faster algorithm for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the current indexes the tables have. Also, what's the specific database? That makes a big difference.

Comment: If you need performance, you should look into the appropriate GIS extensions for your database.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't have permissions to add indexes :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have permissions to do anything to the database besides query

Comment: @Wabbage Post the execution plan of the query.

Comment: Performance is affected by indexes and statistics, not algorithms. If the join columns aren't indexed, you can't improve performance at all.

Comment: Furthermore, what you ask is the distance between two points. Whatever database you use, it probably already has GIS extensions that allow it to calculate the distance. That will only improve performance by 1-2 times. Indexes can improve it by 1000x, 1000000x times - without them, the server has to calculate the Cartesian product of all table rows and check. For just 1000 rows per table, you'd get 1M comparisons.

Comment: Why do you need the `OUTER` join?

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry, I'm also not allowed to include the execution plan for my queries. If there are no other way, then I will see if I can ask for permission to add indexes. Could you please repost the answer you deleted so I can try it out?

Comment: @Wabbage I undeleted the answer as requested.

Answer (score 0):

=== Removed since the OP doesn't have privileges to add indexes ===

Going on a limb I would make sure you have proper indexes in the tables. Add both of these and let the engine to pick the best one:

```
create index ix1 t1 (a, b, c, d);

create index ix2 t2 (a, b, c, d);
```

The engine should perfom a "full scan" on one table and an "index scan/seek" on the other one.

The engine should pick the one of those indexes, according to the cardinality of the tables, selectivity of the predicate (table stats/histograms). Make sure the table stats are up to date.